# How Can I use Nonfactors MVC Grid with Search HttpPost request which should work with paging?

Tags: nonfactors-mvc-grid

I am using NonFactors.MVC.Grid and implementing Pagination, It is not working with HttpPost and I want to use it for Search with Post request. Pagination does not work.

Here is the code:

```
  @model FormModel
     Html.Grid(Model)
        .Build(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add(model =>              model.P1).Titled("P1").
       UsingDefaultFilterMethod("equals").AppendCss("sticky-col first-col");
            columns.Add(model =>   model.P2).Titled("P2").
        UsingDefaultFilterMethod("equals").AppendCss("sticky-col second-col");
           
        })
.Empty("No data found")
.Pageable(pager =>
{
    pager.RowsPerPage = 10;
})
.Filterable()
// Enables single filtering for not explicitly configured property expression columns.
.Sortable()
)
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchResults(FormModel model)
{
IQueryable<Model1>? data=//get data from database.

return View(data);
}
```